# How much memory is allocated in Java when initializing a Object array?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

When Java has no idea how big each element of the array is going to be, how much memory does it allocate?

Comment: Java always knows the size of an array. thats why it requires the number of elements of it.

Comment: There is a header of 32-48 bytes, generally, plus space for the array itself, byte-for-byte.  And the allocation is generally rounded up to some boundary -- 16 bytes or 32 bytes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444395/java-object-and-array-memory-location

Comment: Don't know how I could get this crazy hold crap after my question was answered brilliantly by Oak. Even if my question was unclear @Oak specified exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java always knows exactly how big each element of the array is going to be, because Java has only two kinds of arrays: arrays of primitives or arrays of object references.

If it's an array of primitives (`int`, `long`, etc.) it's the size of the primitive; and if it's an array of objects then it's the size of references to objects (pointers).

Comment: Uh, not exactly... Modern JVMs use compressed pointers (i.e. 4 bytes) when the heap size is less than ~28GB...

Comment: What about `byte[]`, `short[]` and `char[]`?

Comment: @thkala edited to (1) fix this and (2) be more generic. Thanks for the information, though, I didn't know this.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens changed the answer to be more generic. The size of the primitive or the reference is not what I was trying to emphasize anyway. Thanks, though!

Comment: @thkala how does it address with 4 bytes, 28 GB?

Comment: Yeah, it's better to leave the precise sizes out of the answer. They're not really relevant and only cause confusion. :-) The take-away here is that you don't ever have a variable holding an object (or an array of objects), you only ever deal with (an array of) references to objects.

Comment: @eldjon: Object addresses within an 64-bit JVM are alligned at 8-byte boundaries. Therefore each 64-bit address has zero on the three least significant bits. By shifting all addresses rightwards by three bits before storing the reference, you can address 2 ^ (32 + 3) B = 32 GB with only 4-bytes. I assume that the lower actual limit is due to techical reasons...

Comment: @thkala but you said that they use compressed pointers of 4 bytes if the heap size is around 28 GB. but now it is 5 bytes actually

Comment: Why is it 5 bytes? The actual address has been shifted rightwards by 3-bits, so the first byte of those five is zero by definition. There is no need to store it...